# nav bar nonresponsive after UIImagePickerController dismissed

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

On iOS 7 only, the navigation bar in my app does not respond to any touches after a UIImagePickerController is used and then dismissed (whether a pic has been selected or not). The screen below the navigation bar functions as normal, but it is now impossible to navigate Back in the app; the user is stuck on this screen.

I am launching the UIImagePickerController from code, though the rest of the app is laid out in storyboards.

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;
mediaUI.delegate = self;
[controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the log was showing "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for" the launching controller. I was launching the image picker controller immediately from another controller when it appeared. This works OK on iOS 8 but there needs to be a delay on iOS 7. I fixed it by calling my method after a brief delay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are performing these steps correctly!

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

And when you are calling

```
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsEditing = YES;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

**`[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];`**

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this was not the problem.